# Error while trying to rename file in python

Tags: python

Here is my python program to rename files in a directory

```
import os

print os.listdir('FilesFolder')
for a in os.listdir('FilesFolder'):
    os.rename(a,a.translate(None,'0123456789'))
```

the output of the program is as shown below:

```
['3abcde', '1abc', '2abcd']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "checkFiles.py", line 6, in <module>
os.rename(a,a.translate(None,'0123456789'))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

As you can see the files in the folder are located correctly but while trying to rename its throwing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in cwd, and `os.listdir('FilesFolder')` lists the dirs inside `cwd/FilesFolder`.
So the path `cwd/FilesFolder/3abcde` exists, but you're renaming `cwd/3abcde`, which doesn't exist.
This should work:

```
b = os.path.join('FilesFolder', a)
os.rename(b,b.translate(None,'0123456789'))
```

a is inside `FilesFolder`

Comment: And what if the path contains numbers?

Comment: True, but I know the path in this case. The OP didn't ask for a general code. In other words - why join twice when the I know that the path does not contain numbers?